# Close window "oncomplete" not working

Tags: visualforce

Close Window code below was not working i have used the following code:

VF page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function CloseWindow()
    { 
    window.top.close(); 
    UpdateOpener(); 
    }

 </script>

<apex:commandButton id="Save" value="Save PTO Request" action="{!Save}" onComplete="CloseWindow();"  />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ActionStatus tag for this

```
<apex:commandButton id="Save" value="Save PTO Request" action="{!QuickSave}" status="closer"/>
  <apex:actionStatus startText="(Saving...)" stopText="" onStop="CloseWindow();" id="closer"/>
```

Use the same script as you have used. And use this code. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you close the window JavaScript no longer executes. No code can run following the page closing.  This is a browser security feature.